# How can I modify Bucket properties

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to write a bucket policy which uses intrinsic function !GetAtt to get attributes from bucket but I am not sure how to write it for multiple buckets.

For single bucket without using intrinsic function, its something like;

```
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "s3:*"
            Resource: [
              "arn:aws:s3:::ExampleBucketName",
              "arn:aws:s3:::ExampleBucketName/*"
              ]
```

I am trying to do this with intrinsic function for multiple buckets but I am not getting it right for sub directory part. How do I go inside  the directory /* using !GetAtt?

My code looks like this;

```
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "s3:*"
            Resource: [
              !GetAtt "ExampleBucketOne.Arn",
              !GetAtt "ExampleBucketOne.Arn"/"*",
              !GetAtt "ExampleBucketTwo.Arn",
              !GetAtt "ExampleBucketTwo.Arn"/"*"
               ]
```

I know the alternate second lines in resource section, ending with /*, are wrong and that's why I am asking for help. What's the correct way?

Comment: Have you tried creating such a policy manually first, to see whether it works? I know that, in the console, the Bucket Policy editor won't allow a reference to a different bucket, so I'm suspecting that it won't be possible to write one Bucket Policy that refers to two different buckets. (Which makes sense, since the bucket policy is only placed on one bucket.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a join to add the `/*` onto the end.

```
!Join [ "", [ !GetAtt "ExampleBucketOne.Arn","/*" ] ]
```

The syntax above is just off the top of my head, so you may need to double check it, but the basic syntax is:

```
!Join [ ":", [ a, b, c ] ]
```

which will result in:

```
a:b:c
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Comment: figured it out shortly after posting the question but good to get a confirmation that I wasn't wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [`!Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) which is a little bit easier to use.

```
        Effect: "Allow"
        Action: "s3:*"
        Resource:
          - !Sub ${ExampleBucketOne.Arn}
          - !Sub ${ExampleBucketOne.Arn}/*
          - !Sub ${ExampleBucketTwo.Arn}
          - !Sub ${ExampleBucketTwo.Arn}/*
```